# How do I find a dynamic programming solution to a maximum satisfaction, shortest time problem?

Tags: python, optimization, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to find an optimization solution using dynamic programming (in python) to the following problem:

Assuming there are satisfaction values, time required to achieve such satisfactions, and an optimal time (that is compared to each individual time), how can the satisfaction values be arranged to get maximum satisfaction in the shortest possible time.

If the satisfaction values, are represented by s, and the time to achieve satisfaction, t, the pair of vectors can be represented as:

```
<(s1, t1), (s2, t2) ... (sn, tn)>
```

I've come up with a rough solution to the problem:

```
    def pp(satifactions, satisfaction_values, time_values, optimal_time, memo):
      list4 = []
    
      for i, j in zip(satisfaction_values, time_values):
        if (i,j,optimal_time) not in memo:
          memo[i,j,optimal_time] = (i * (optimal_time/j))
          list4.append(memo[i,j,optimal_time])

      zipped_lists = zip(list4, satifactions)
      sorted_pairs = sorted(zipped_lists)

      tuples = zip(*sorted_pairs)
      list4, satifactions= [list(tuple) for tuple in  tuples]
      return list(reversed(satifactions))

    def getPP (satifactions, satisfaction_values, time_values, optimal_time):
      memo = {}
      return pp(satifactions, satisfaction_values, time_values, optimal_time, memo)

    print(getPP(["LOK", "MP", "HM", "AR", "SG", "VV"], [0.37, 0.87, 0.27, 0.87, 0, 0.56], [6, 1, 15, 3, 3, 3], 6))
```

My questions are:

1. Can this be considered a dynamic solution to the problem?
2. What variant of the knapsack problem can it be considered to be?
3. How can I mathematically represent it?

Comment: This is a variation of knapsack

Comment: s is value, t is weight.

Comment: @ChristianSloper How do I factor in the optimal time, considering the knapsack problem has a restriction of maximum cumulative capacity, but in my case, the time to achieve individual satisfaction is compared individually with the optimal time?

Comment: Knapsack solutions give you a table of "maximum achievable satisfaction in time t", you can look up any satisfaction and find the minimum time possible to achieve that satisfaction level.

Comment: In terms or programming I would venture that a transformation is requireed to change your vectors to (wsn,tn) where wsn is the weighted satisfaction wrt. time needed and simply remove from vector max(wsn) given that tn< X and continue until X is 0 or > than all tn.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking, can you please clarify? Are you looking for a solution, or in general for the name of the class of problems? "How do I factor in the optimal time, say X to the equation?" – what equation?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I was looking for a classification of the general problem. It's been stated to be a variation of the knapsack problem. I was also looking for a solution to the problem where the vector pairs can be ordered in terms of the minimum time to achieve the most satisfaction like: <(s4, t4), (s1, t1), (s2, t2), (s3, t3)> wrt any given optimal time, x.